# How to auto reference?

Tags: 7

I have created 2 content types one is called Album and the other is Image. I gave Image a reference field so it's linking to Album. Now when a user goes to upload a image how can I make it auto reference to the album? cause the user will have no knowledge in using drupal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [nodereference url](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) module. It's designed exactly for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the module [Node Reference URL Widget](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url). With this module you can create a link in your content type Album, so when the user clicks on it, takes him to the content type image to upload the picture and your reference field will take from the url the id of that Album.

Easy to configure.